# How to render jsx element more than the props items (array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react component, I am receiving one element as props. Now I want to render 9 more elements in the list. How can I achieve that? Is it possible to achieve it by Array.map()?

```
function List(props) {
//here props.number = [1]

return (
  <ul>
  // Here I want to render list items 10 times. (without using for loop)
    {
      props.number.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)
}
```

Comment: What sort of `key` / content do you want for the new items?

Comment: If props.number is [1] then I would need 10 list items [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
But if props.number = [5], then I would need only 6 list items [5,6,7,8,9,10]

And the list content will be same as array items.

Comment: Will the `.number` array only contain exactly one element? That's kinda weird for an array

Comment: Yeah, it contains only one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the number, construct a new array containing the numbers you want, then `.map` and return it:

```
const [num] = props.number;
const arrToDisplay = Array.from({ length: 11 - num }, (_, i) => i + num);
return (
  <ul>
    {
      arrToDisplay.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)
```

```js
const getArr = (num) => {
  const arrToDisplay = Array.from({ length: 11 - num }, (_, i) => i + num);
  console.log(arrToDisplay);
};
getArr(1);
getArr(5);
getArr(10);
```